# Are you able to delete a pre-loaded game from your 3DS? How do you re-download it?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, new-nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds-2dsxl

I have a 3DS that came with a game pre-loaded on it.  How would I go about deleting the game (NOT the data if possible) off of the system to free up space?  And since I never actually received a game code or cartridge, how would I go about re-downloading that game?

Comment: You never received a game code? Are you sure? When I got my 2DS with Mario Kart 7 bundle it just came with a download code.

Comment: The Animal Crossing New Leaf 3DS came with the game pre-loaded, there was no install needed as it was there when the system booted up for the first time.

Comment: Interesting, I guess it just depends on which bundle. I'm guessing that in the E-shop there is a way to tell if it thinks you've purchased the game (for example a 'purchased page' or if you go to the game page it says you already own it) if it does think you've purchased it I'd imagine its safe to delete and re-install later since it won't make you pay to re-download a game you own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are able to delete a pre-loaded game from your 3DS (as it is treated as a eShop purchase).

You can redownload it as any other eShop game that you have purchased in the past.

You need to be logged in a Nintendo Network ID account so the game is linked, since you need a NNID to be able to enter eShop, that souldn't be an issue.

[Here](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/570/~/how-to-delete-save-data-and-applications) you can read further in detail.

> **Once deleted, pre-installed software** (Mario Kart 7, Swapnote, Fire Emblem: Awakening) **and Nintendo eShop purchases can be redownloaded at no cost.**

Also in the link provided there is a guide on how to delete your game without losing your saved data.

> - Select the data you would like to delete, then select "Delete."
> - Tap "Delete Software and Save Data" or "**Create Save-Data Backup and Delete Software.**"
>
>   - **If you have selected to back up the save data, you can do so using an    existing folder or you can create a new one.**
> - Tap "Delete" again to confirm.

And [here](https://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/607) is a guide on how to redownload games from the eShop.

Comment: Excellent information and answer again.